ggpairs(): customising select facets different from the rest (e.g. unique themes)
I want to have more control over the customisation of individual facets of the ggpairs() plot below.

The upper right factes that show the correlation coefficients:

1.1) These facets should have a white background and not share the panel grid lines
1.2) The text "Corr:" should be black and not grey
1.3) The text lines should be centred on their left or in the middle, but they appear shifted

The lower scatter plots and diagonal density plots:

2.1) They should have normal lines as their x and y axis (left and lower border of each facet) but no lines on the top and right borders
This is the code I have produced thus far:
ggpairs(
  data = mydata,
  mapping = aes(color = de.novo, fill = de.novo), 
  columns = c("rmsd", "pLDDT (AF2)", "ipTM (AF2)", "iPAE (AF2)"),
  
  upper = list(
    continuous = wrap("cor", size = 5),
    {panel.grid.major = element_blank()} 
  ),
  
  lower = list(
    continuous = wrap("points", size = 0.2, alpha = 0.25) 
  ),
  
  diag = list(
    continuous = wrap("densityDiag", alpha = 0.5) 
  )
)+
  
  scale_fill_manual(values = c("#3E049CFF", "#C03A83FF", "#FCD225FF")) + 
  scale_color_manual(values = c("#3E049CFF", "#C03A83FF", "#FCD225FF")) +
  
  theme_bw() +
  theme(
    panel.grid.minor.x = element_blank(),
    panel.border       = element_blank(),
    
    axis.title.y = element_text(size = 29.5, vjust = 2.5),
    axis.title.x = element_text(size = 29.5, vjust = -0.1),
    
    axis.text.y.left = element_text(color = "black", size = 23),
    axis.text.x.bottom= element_text(color = "black", size = 23),
    
    axis.ticks.y.left = element_line(linewidth=1.6, color = "black", unit(4, "pt")), 
    axis.ticks.length.y.left = unit(0.18, "cm"),
    
    axis.ticks.x.bottom = element_line(linewidth=1.6, color = "black", unit(4, "pt")),
    axis.ticks.length.x.bottom = unit(0.18, "cm"),
    
    strip.text.x = element_text(
      size = 23, color = "black"),
    
    strip.text.y = element_text(
      size = 23, color = "black"),
    
    strip.background = element_rect(
      color="black", fill="white", size=1.5, linetype="solid"),
    
    plot.margin = margin(22,16,7,10, "points")
  )

print(ggplot)

producing this plot (please ignore truncated and crashing axis text):

I have found the following questions going in a similar direction for my problem 1.1), but I was unable adapting them to this case:
Change colors in ggpairs now that params is deprecated
ggpairs() correlation values without gridlines
GGally::ggpairs plot without gridlines when plotting correlation coefficient
R GGally::ggpairs, corrlation matrix plot, how to custom diag
These are questions similar to my problem 1.3), but the align_percent() and hjust solutions did not work:
Adjust group text aesthetics in ggpairs()
GGpairs, correlation values are not aligned
For Problem 2), I have tried specifying unique theme components in upper(), lower() and diag(). For instance:
upper( ... 
theme(panel.grid.minor.x = element_blank()...)

This would be the easiest solution, but it did not work.
